# Vue/Nuxt - Mouseleave triggers from child element

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, nuxt.js

Currently trying to build a portion of my site that when text is hovered over, a modal box appears below it (so people can hover over it). This would keep the modal present until they move their mouse outside of this.

The issue I face is as soon as my mouse moves from the text to the modal, the model dismisses (as it seems the mouseleave event is triggered).

```html
<div class="relative" @mouseover="guestDropdown = true" @mouseout="guestDropdown = false">
  <p class="flex items-center justify-between mt-4 text-xs font-medium leading-4 text-gray-600">
    <span>Input:</span>
    <span class="cursor-pointer text-deepskyblue-500">Hover</span>
  </p>
  <div class="absolute right-0 z-20 mt-2 -mx-3 bg-white border rounded" v-show="guestDropdown">
    <p class="px-3 py-2">Some modal!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more code and reproducible example but `mouseover`/`mouseout` [trigger on descendants](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave) which is probably something you don't want in this case. You can use `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` instead - those doesn't trigger on descendants and doesn't bubble...

Comment: Hey, apologies! Click [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sea-qiwzl?file=/pages/index.vue) for a reproducible example.

Comment: OK, I see you now switched to using `mouseenter/mouseleave` and it seems working pretty well (FF 81) - when text is hovered, popup shows up and is closed only when mouse leaves text or popup. Isn't that what you wanted ?